# how to move uploaded file in php?

Tags: php, html

Here is my html code for uploading multiple files in php. I want to store the image name in the database and upload the file in folder:

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><br />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple="multiple"/><br />

if(isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
            $num_files = count($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
            for($i=0; $i < $num_files;$i++){
                if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i])){
                    $messages[] = 'No file uploaded';
                }
                else{
                    if (file_exists("images/Locations" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
                      {

                      }
                    else
                      {
                      if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
                      $file = fopen("test.txt","w");
                            echo fwrite($file,"Not uploaded");
                            fclose($file);
                        }
                        else{
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],"images/Locations");
                        }
                      }

                }
            }
    }
```

So can anyone tell me where I am making a mistake.  I want to store name of image into database so how can i do that when i am writing the error it displays error code 0, so what is error code 0 in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistakes that I found at the first sight was:

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple/><br />
```

This should there only once because of the multiple attribute it forms multi-dimensional array according to the number of images selected.

Change your if-conditional to

```
if(count($_FILES['userfile']['name']> 0)){
```

That should give you a start. Let me know if you find any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your input file type name is `"userfile"`

And you are using in the PHP script as

```
$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
```

And here is the problem.

Change them accordingly to use proper input names on your script processing the upload.